# join table to table related to the parent table

Tags: c#, linq

Still new to LINQ so be nice.

This query:

```
var query = _ODSContext.AllFacilities
.Where(f => f.AllFacilityContacts.Any(c => ProviderContactIds.Contains(c.ContactID) && 
(c.ContactTypeName == "Primary Rep")))
.Where(f => f.TermDate > DateTime.Now)
.Include(a => a.Address)
.Include(b => b.AllFacilityContacts)
.Include(c => c.AllPractitionerLocations)
.Include(e => e.AllFacilityServices)
.OrderBy(f => f.FacilityName);
```

works fine.

However, I want to add a table that joins to  AllpractitionerLocations:

Here's what I tried:

```
var query = _ODSContext.AllFacilities
.Where(f => f.AllFacilityContacts.Any(c => ProviderContactIds.Contains(c.ContactID) && 
(c.ContactTypeName == "Primary Rep")))
.Where(f => f.TermDate > DateTime.Now)
.Include(a => a.Address)
.Include(b => b.AllFacilityContacts)
.Include(c => c.AllPractitionerLocations)
.Include(d => d.AllPractitionerNetworkSpecialty)
.Include(e => e.AllFacilityServices)
.OrderBy(f => f.FacilityName);
```

But I get:

```
'AllFacility' does not contain a definition for 
'AllPractitionerNetworkSpecialties' and no accessible extension method 
'AllPractitionerNetworkSpecialties' accepting a first argument of type 
'AllFacility' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Which is technically accurate. AllPractitionerNetworkSpecialties is related to AllPractitionerLocations.

How do I do the join between those two tables in LINQ?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to show entities definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use ThenInclude

Simplistically, `Include` starts off from the root entity, `ThenInclude` carries on from the entity type that you call it on. If you conceive your graph as a hub-spoke type affair with AllFacilities as the hub, your Include starts another spoke from the hub, whereas ThenInclude continues an existing spoke. If a customer has orders and orders have products, you'd `context.Customer.Include(... Orders).ThenInclude(... Products)`. If you wanted to "go back to the hub" and get the Customer>Address>Country>TaxYearCodings you'd

```
context.Customer
  .Include(... Orders)
    .ThenInclude(... Products)
  .Include(... Address)
    .ThenInclude(... Country)
      .ThenInclude(... TaxYearCodings)
```

We (at work) tend to indent another level when we ThenInclude to signify "continuing a spoke", and indent all the Includes the same to signify "going back to the hub".

Possibly also worth pointing out that you can chain your Include and ThenInclude by accessing the chain "in a one-er" but you can't navigate into collections, only single props - you start another inclusion when you hit a collection

```
customer.Include(c => c.Address.Country.TaxYearCodings).ThenInclude(tyc => ...)
```

Be careful; the amount of data you load when you start (then)including a lot can be enormous

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks like that's exactly what I need. Can you answer one more little bit for me please? I want to filter the ThenInclude. Where would I put the Where for that? Thanks

Comment: If you're using EF 5 you can put it in the `[Then]Include` on a collection `customer.Include(c => c.Orders,Where(o => o.Status == "New").ThenInclude(o => o.Products.Where(o => p.StockLevel>0) /* universally false in 2021 ;) */)`. If older, you can put a Where clause on the main query. Accesses you make in the Where may remove the need to use Include anyway as EF will perform joins and retrieve data based on what it finds in a Whwre, but include is a nicer syntax